# Multi-OS bootable USB

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, usb

Right, I'm new here so I'm incredibly sorry if this has been answered elsewhere...

But I was wondering if it was possible to have a USB that can boot into both Linux (e.g Ubunutu, Kali) but can also boot into multiple versions of Windows (e.g 10, 7) or even work so that I could wipe a HDD of the current Windows installation or delete partitions etc...?

Frankly, I'm new to Linux as well and it would come in handy for what I am about to start studying and I am genuinely interested on how to do it (if it can be done).

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Windows only boots from internal hard drives, not from USB flash drives. It license is for one system only. So only Windows installer can be on flash drive. You can do full installs of Ubuntu or other Linux which if larger flash drive, then is just like any install to external drive or install multiple ISO to flash drive and boot with grub, but ISO are not updateable.

Comment: I would have asked this on U+L ( http://unix.stackexchange.com/) and not here. Windows: off topic, Kali: off topic.

Answer (score 3):

## Can I have more than one version of Linux that I can boot from on a USB?

Yes, there are multiple programs out there that can help mount more than one ISO file to a USB and make two seperate partitions to boot from. Here are two that I can recommend:

- [MultiBootUSB](http://multibootusb.org/)
- [XBoot](https://sites.google.com/site/shamurxboot/)

Just make sure you have enough space.

Answer (score 0):

you can install windowstogo(WINDOWS 8) to usb.This is not installer but OS.

---

To multiboot it my advice is to use gpt partition system with usb. You'll need additional  grub patition(~2mb) there. run  `grub-mkconfig -o (usb part)/boot/grub/grub.cfg` and then `grub-install --boot-directory=(usb part)/boot/   (usb)`  .ie `mount /dev/sdb2 /mnt`      grub-mkconfig -o /mnt/boot/grub/grub.cfg

NEW

you can copy images to same usb part-n,then edit  usb part)/boot/grub/grub.cfg .Remove all menuentries there exept that's you unerstand are about

and add

> menuentry "Xubuntu (32bit)" {
>
> iso_path=/xubuntu-13.10-dvd-i386.iso
>
> export iso_path
>
> search --set --file $iso_path
>
> loopback loop $iso_path
>
> root=(loop)
>   configfile /boot/grub/loopback.cfg
>
> > loopback --delete loop
>
> }

somethin like that for each iso

Comment: immediately after the "windows to go" question'd put to on hold or so.